# Yii2 - How to implement RBAC Authorization in RESTful API?

Tags: api, rest, yii2, authorization, rbac

HI I just discovered Yii framework and I need some guidelines to implement this...

[Yii2 RBAC - Official Guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html#rbac)

...in my RESTful app. I know I have to [override](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/2754) the method `[checkAccess][3]()` in my controllers but I can't found any example. My API has token based Beare autentication and sessions are disabled (stateless).

Comment: Use RBAC as usual. You'll have user identity if you send right token.

Comment: @SiZE got it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your controller:

```
public function behaviors()
    {
        $behaviors = parent::behaviors();

        $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
            'class' => CompositeAuth::className(),
            'authMethods' => [
                HttpBearerAuth::className(),
            ],
        ];

        // add CORS filter
        $behaviors['corsFilter'] = [
            'class' => Cors::className(),
            'cors' => [
                'Origin' => ['*'],
                'Access-Control-Request-Method' => ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS'],
                'Access-Control-Request-Headers' => ['*'],
            ],
        ];

        // avoid authentication on CORS-pre-flight requests (HTTP OPTIONS method)
        $behaviors['authenticator']['except'] = ['options', 'login', 'signup'];

        $behaviors['access'] = [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'only' => [
                'update',
                'delete',
                'view',
                'index',
            ],
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'actions' => [
                        'update',
                        'delete',
                        'view',
                        'index',
                    ],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
            ],
        ];

        $behaviors['verbFilter'] = [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'signup' => ['POST'],
                'login' => ['POST'],
                'update' => ['PUT'],
                'delete' => ['DELETE'],
                'view' => ['GET'],
                'index' => ['GET'],
            ],
        ];

        return $behaviors;
    }
```

Comment: This is not a good answer, please tell more about code or resolving.